# Flutter add to new cart if diffrent product size

Tags: flutter

Hello i have simple e commerce application. When a new product is added to the cart, I can add it, but when a different size arrives, I want to register a new one, how can I solve this?

My cart code;

```
void addItem(
    String productId,
    String title,
    double price,
    String image,
    String size,
  ) {
    if (_items.containsKey(productId)) {
      _items.update(
        productId,
        (prevCartItem) => Cart(
          id: prevCartItem.id,
          title: prevCartItem.title,
          image: prevCartItem.image,
          quantity: prevCartItem.quantity + 1,
          price: prevCartItem.price,
          size: prevCartItem.size,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      _items.putIfAbsent(
        productId,
        () => Cart(
          id: DateTime.now().toString(),
          title: title,
          quantity: 1,
          image: image,
          price: price,
          size: size,
        ),
      );
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the item is a cloth or of some kind where the user will have to select a size in order to add that item

Let size to be sizes in your item class and make it a map

Your code will look something like this..

```
if (_items.containsKey(productId)) {
  if (_items[productId]['sizes'].containsKey(size))
    _items[productId]['sizes'][size]++;
    else{
      _items[productId]['sizes'][size] = 1;
    }
} else {
  _items.putIfAbsent(
    productId,
    () => Cart(
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
      title: title,
      quantity: 1,
      image: image,
      price: price,
      sizes: {[size]:1},
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually the code looks correct, but what I want to do is not update the size. Add a new one cart item when different size.

Comment: Then you should have a different id for each size or else you could do sth like `_items.putIfAbsent( productId + size, ...`

Answer (score 0):

it will alway update prevCart because " It have same ID " you just have to add condition to check did prevCart have same item size to finish this
concept : if(_items.containsKey(productId)) => if(_items.containsKey(productId) && prevCartItem.size != size )

Comment: how to arrive prevCartItem before update? can you share example code with me?

Comment: I already share my cart addItem code. What code do you want exactly?

Comment: if your _item is model you can try to add this 
https://pastebin.com/H4WndAQ0

Answer (score 0):

I add

```
_items.putIfAbsent(

    (productId + size),
    () => Cart(
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
      title: title,
      quantity: 1,
      image: image,
      price: price,
      sizes: {[size]:1},
    ),
  );
```

and it worked, but now the `"if"` stopped working even if I add the `+"size"`